# ROS Answers SE migration: GLX missing

Tags: ros, rviz, nvidia, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When tying to run rviz I get a bunch of this message:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

What is causing this? The rviz splash screen just flash in a sec. Using diamondback on Ubuntu 10.10.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9610/glx-missing/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-03-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-03-30**:
What's your graphics card? Are you using the proprietary drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I resolved it by reinstalling nvidia drivers after a linux kernel update.

---

Originally posted by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) with karma: 475 on 2011-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2